# JavaFx How to hide / show TreeItem

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TreeItem (a Tree with 100+ TreeItems  elements).
I want to give the user the ability to hide (or show again) some TreeItems. (So the user will see just the items he care about).

I cant see a property of TreeItem which give me the ability to show or hide.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show/hide any TreeItem in TreeView you should add or remove it:

```
parentTreeItem.getChildren().remove(treeItem);
...
parentTreeItem.getChildren().add(treeItem);
```

Comment: But then I need to pay attention where I add back the Item (save the order)...no ?

Comment: Yes :) This is why I hate JavaFX sometimes. In Swing you can make custom data model and just filter data inside it to hide or show tree items. BUT in JavaFX you should rebuild all hierarchy of TreeItem's.